# Django: Best way to join data from multiple, associate models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I am new to Django and want to write code the complies with its ideology.  I looked to see if this was asked before, but I couldn't find anything that matched my use case.  I suspect I just don't know the proper terminology.

The situation is simple and involves Django's ORM. I have two models, for example:

```
class A(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField()

class Meta(models.Model):
 a = models.OneToOneField(A)
 n_views = models.IntegerField()
 created = models.DateField()
```

A stores some core data.  Meta is meta-data that corresponds to each entry into A.  The problem comes that, frequently, when I need to access the entries of A and the associated meta-data entries  For example, I might want to print a summary table:

```
________________________
A                       |
name | created | n_views|
josh | 1/1/2000| 1      |
john | 2/2/2000| 4      |
________________________
```

What I do right now is something like this:

```
as = A.objects.all()
meta = [Meta.objects.filter(a__pk=a.pk) for a in as]
```

Now I have all the data I need and I can put it together, by hand, in a list:

```
data = []
for a,m in zip(as, meta):
 data.append({'name': a.meta, 'created': m.created, 'n_views': m.n_views})
```

This list of dicts can now be forwarded to my template.

This works, but it seems a little clumsy to me; I would be surprised if Django doesn't have some better way of dealing with this.  Can anyone point me to a more succinct way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
objs = A.objects.select_related().all()
for a in objs:
    print(a.name, a.meta.n_views, a.meta.created)
```

which will let Django construct a query that queries for both `A` objects and `Meta` objects.

Comment: This looks like a good solution but I cannot stop myself from pointing out that you should not use `as` since it's a Python reserved word.  https://docs.python.org/2.5/ref/keywords.html

Comment: Sorry, that 'as' was just some example code I threw out without much thought.  Good point.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted!  Thanks, Simeon.